# Nginx configuration passing fastcgi parameter and rewriting depending on location

Tags: nginx

I'm searching a way to configure nginx with the a php applciation.

It should serve static files if they exists. If they are in the subfolder /dev, they are only allowed for the 127.0.0.1;

An uri which isn't a static file should be redirected to php via the third location block.

If this uri which goes to php starts with /dev, I want the uri to be rewrited without the /dev, and the fastcgi_param APP_ENV set to "dev". (And also be blocked for any except 127.0.0.1)

If this uri does not start with /dev, I just want to set fastcgi_param APP_ENV  to "prod", without rewriting.

```
server {
    root /var/www/homeserver/public;

    location /dev {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;

        # This has no effect on the third location block:
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;

        # This is only OK for when try_files pass the uri to /index.php
        rewrite ^/dev(.*)$ /$1 last; 

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        # This has no effect on the third location block:
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod; 

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Front controler :
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;        

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

I tried to solve this using "if" statements. Without success.

How can I configure it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration(I didn't tested it, but I hope it should do what you want).

```
server {
    root /var/www/homeserver/public;

    location /dev {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;

        rewrite ^/dev/(.*)$ /$1 break; 

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            gzip off;
            expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
              return 404 "Error 404 Not found. (err#002)";
            }

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";  # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            # fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root; # DOCUMENT_ROOT already specified in fastcgi_params
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            gzip off;
            expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
              return 404 "Error 404 Not found. (err#001)";
            }

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
            fastcgi_index index.php; 
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";  # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            # fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root; # DOCUMENT_ROOT already specified in fastcgi_params
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but isn't it possible to simplify the configuration using only one ".php" location block ?

Comment: You can, but as author of nginx said on some conference, - it is Ok and even advisable to use copy-paste method in nginx configs instead of trying to organize it logically . To get better understanding how nginx process directives, you need to know in which phases directives are executed. To keep error-less and predictable behavior of nginx it is better for you and nginx to concentrate attention on each particular location instead of use kinda pattern as in programming by combining stuff in all-in-one processing location